# Is there something like "Requestor Pays" with Amazon S3 but where requestor pays for storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

Is there a cloud service where I can allow users to upload files and also pay for them at the same time?  Or is there a way to do it on S3, like "[Requestor Pays](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html)" but where requestor pays for storage and uploading?

I want to have essentially public inbound storage where the person would pay say $0.01 for uploading 1MB. Perhaps the file would only be stored for a month (since they only paid a fixed amount, not for potentially infinite storage)

Answer (score -1):

You're talking about a service offering. If you want to find the service offering so that you can show it to user, the user too can find you and avoid you from being a middleman. A good idea will be creating a bucket and then build an app to allow users to upload files. Cognito can be used for authentication. Also, you can use SAM for your portal. If you want to charge user per their usage, you should keep track of their usage too.